# Watch multiple files with Grunt Bake without compiling all at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want to use [Grunt Bake](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake) for my grunt workflow. This is my grunt.js setup:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    bake: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'dev/foo.html': 'public/foo.html',
                'dev/bar.html': 'public/bar.html',
                'dev/foo2.html': 'public/foo2.html'
                // ...
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        bake: {
            files: ['dev/*.html'],
            tasks: ['bake:build']
        }
    }

});
```

My problem: If I change **one** file **all** files will be compiled. I could solve this with creating a watch listener for each file but this seems not to be a clever solution:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    bake: {
        foo: {
            files: {
                'dev/foo.html': 'public/foo.html'
            }
        },
        bar: {
            files: {
                'dev/bar.html': 'public/bar.html'
            }
        },
        foo2: {
            files: {
                'dev/foo2.html': 'public/foo2.html'
            }
        }
        // ...
    },

    watch: {
        foo1: {
            files: ['dev/foo.html'],
            tasks: ['bake:foo']
        },
        bar: {
            files: ['dev/bar.html'],
            tasks: ['bake:bar']
        },
        foo2: {
            files: ['dev/foo2.html'],
            tasks: ['bake:foo2']
        }
    }

});
```

Imagine there are 20+ different html files... So this is not an option for me. Any other solutions for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it!

There is a [newer task](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) exactly for doing this:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    bake: {
        build: {
           files: {
                'dev/foo.html': 'public/foo.html',
                'dev/bar.html': 'public/bar.html',
                'dev/foo2.html': 'public/foo2.html'
                // ...
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        bake: {
            files: ['dev/*.html'],
            tasks: ['newer:bake:build']
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: If you can answer your own question I think you can mark it as resolved for yourself if that solves the problem. (which it clearly does in your case). PS: cheers for using grunt-bake. Hope It's helpful. :)